# Getting response %40 in place of @ how should i convert it

Tags: php, jquery

This function searches for %40 instead of @ in the query:

```
public function check_email() {
  $main = ($_POST['main']);
  $this->load->database();
  $this->db->where('email', $main);
  $query = $this->db->get('abc');
}
```

What do I need to change for it to not replace @ by %40

Answer (score 4):

You can use `urldecode();`

`echo urldecode("%40"); // @`

Comment: where should i use ? @Daan

Comment: `$main = urldecode($main);` put this under `$main = ($_POST['main']);`